# adding an array to a csv file in second column using ruby

Tags: ruby, csv

I am trying to automate a search on Google because I have more than 1 thousand lines. I can read and automate my search from the CSV, but I cannot add the array to the file. Maybe I'm missing something?

For the test, the CSV file is made up of 1 column with no header and 3 rows.

Here is my code:

```
require 'watir'
require 'nokogiri'
require 'csv'

browser = Watir::Browser.new(:chrome)
browser.goto("http://www.google.com")
CSV.open('C:\Users\Market\Documents\Emailhunter_scraper\test-email.csv').map do |terms|
browser.text_field(title: "Rechercher").set terms
browser.send_keys :return

sleep(rand(10))
doc = Nokogiri::HTML.parse(browser.html)
doc.css("div.f kv _SWb").each do |item|
  name = item.css('a').text
  link = item.css('a')[:href]
  csv << [name, link]
end
sleep(rand(10))
end
sleep(rand(10))
```

Comment: I'm guessing the issue is that you haven't opened up the CSV file for writing. Try this: `CSV.open('path/to/file/csv', 'wb')`

Comment: Thanks for your solutions, indeed it does write in my csv. Only problem is: it writes nothing and erases everything written...
What am I doing wrong?
My csv file has 2 columns (entities,url) and 3 rows (a,b,c)
I know how I can tell Ruby to look for each row but not how I can tell Ruby to write in column url the link parsed corresponding to the entity read. I don't know if I'm clear enough so don't hesitate to hit me back ;)

Comment: Any update on my problem?

Answer (score 1):

As shown in [the documentation for `CSV.open`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html#method-c-open), the file `mode` defaults to `"rb"`.

This means the file is being opened as **read-only**. Instead, you need to use:

```
CSV.open('path/to/file/csv', 'wb')
```

The full documentation for different modes can be seen [here](http://ruby-doc.org/core/IO.html#method-c-new). They are:

```
"r"  Read-only, starts at beginning of file  (default mode).

"r+" Read-write, starts at beginning of file.

"w"  Write-only, truncates existing file
     to zero length or creates a new file for writing.

"w+" Read-write, truncates existing file to zero length
     or creates a new file for reading and writing.

"a"  Write-only, each write call appends data at end of file.
     Creates a new file for writing if file does not exist.

"a+" Read-write, each write call appends data at end of file.
     Creates a new file for reading and writing if file does
     not exist.

"b"  Binary file mode
     Suppresses EOL <-> CRLF conversion on Windows. And
     sets external encoding to ASCII-8BIT unless explicitly
     specified.

"t"  Text file mode
```

Comment: OMG i'm so stupid! you answered me ages ago and I just understood... Thank you so much!